# Python logging over multiple projects

Tags: python, logging, project

Lots has been written about logging in Python, but I have not found anything comprehensive about aligning logging over multiple projects. For instance it is not unreasonable to assume that people reuse projects publicized on Github (That's what it is there for). 
I believe that any project needs logging, especially those under development, so my question is, how do I make logging as open and available as possible?

Recently I have been a fan of loading a configuration file in the `__init__.py` of the main package.

```
import logging.config
import sys
from traceback import print_exception

fileconf = "logging.conf"
try:
    logging.config.fileConfig(fileconf)
except:
    print "Could not use %s for configuration because:" % (fileconf,)
    print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
```

Then each module will get a logger from a dedicated logging module, `logger.py`:

```
import logging

def get_logger(name):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    return logger
```

Unfortunately I do not see the straightforward extension to multiple projects. I would like to be able to use the same configuration file as standard.

So how do I create projects that make easy use of the logging configuration of super projects? Perhaps checking if logging is already configured somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add logging capabilities to a project then you just need to use the loggers and leave the configuration to whoever/whatever is going to use them.

For example, let's say you want to log something inside a module:

```
def my_method():
    try:
        # do something...
    except Exception as e:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.error("error doing something: {}".format(e))
```

`__name__` returns the modules name including the package path (e.g. project.path.to.module) so now whoever needs to use this project or multiple projects using logging the same way will load their own configuration file and define logging settings per project.

Avoid loading configurations at the module level but leave it optional (inside a method or `if __name__ == '__main__'` in order to avoid conflicts)

This seems like a good reference for good logging practices: http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python

Comment: Though I understand why you wouldn't want a logger on the module level, I prefer it over getting a logger at the class level or for each log statement.

Comment: In this case you'll risk getting the logger before the configurations have been loaded (unless you set `disable_existing_loggers` to False in your configs. I don't see the trade off of getting the logger at the module level really, it's a pretty cheap operation to just get the logger at the class init or methods. Check the link in my post above for good practices.

Answer (score 1):

Library projects should never configure logging (though they might provide helpers to do so). Logging should only be configured by main programs, and that also in their `if __name__ == '__main__'` code path. In the case you describe, this would be in a package's `__main__.py` (as this is what's used to run packages) rather than `__init__.py` (it's best to avoid import-time side effects where possible).

I don't understand what value there is in your `logger.py`, since using

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

(in each module which does logging) works pretty well for most people, most of the time.

If you want to use a standard configuration file, stick to configuring handlers for the root logger only (since otherwise, you would be configuring project-specific loggers). If you use `dictConfig()` rather than `fileConfig()`, it allows more flexibility in terms of e.g. merging configuration dictionaries from libraries with your main configuration.

Comment: I used to have additional actions that I wanted to perform on each logger, but that is no longer necessary, which is why I have logger.py. `__main__.py` is a very nice suggestion.